# How to create map elements or dictionary from a list in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a list of elements in Groovy script:

```
my_list = ['key_1', 'value_1', 'key_2', 'value_2']
```

I want to turn this list to a Groovy map of elements (aka dictionary aka hash aka associative array) so it would look like:

```
[key_1: 'value_1', key_2: 'value_2']
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Will the order always be the same ? What if the list is `['key_1', 'key_3', 'key_2', 'value_2']` ? It's generally not safe to make assumptions about position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much shorter method is:

```
def ​my_list = ['key_1', 'value_1', 'key_2', 'value_2']
​
def my_map = my_list.collate(2, false).collectEntries()
​
assert my_map == ['key_1':'value_1', 'key_2':'value_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, depending on the reliability of the order in your list:

```
my_list = ['key_1', 'value_1', 'key_2', 'value_2']

my_map = [:]

my_list.eachWithIndex { item, idx ->
    if (idx % 2 == 0) {
        my_map[my_list[idx]] = my_list[idx+1]
    }
}

assert my_map == ['key_1':'value_1', 'key_2':'value_2']
```